# how to find the intersection of 2 different size 2d tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

there are 2 tensor vectors, size `[8,2]` and `[8,32]`, `(dim=0 is same, dim=1 is different)` I want to get the intersection of each dim:

```
t1 = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [4,5,6]])
t2 = torch.tensor([[1],[3],[9]])
```

I want to get:

```
t3 = [[1],[3],[]]
```

Comment: The shapes you have provided don't match the example you gave. Can you provide a more representative example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I want to express that the two vectors can be of any size, but dim=0 is the same and dim=1 is different, such as [2,3] and [2,1], or [8,1] and [8,256]. So the example gives two random numbers that dim=0 is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you part-way there:

```
t1 = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [4,5,6]])
t2 = torch.tensor([[1],[3],[9]])

def intersection(t1, t2):
     t1 = t1.unique()
     t2 = t2.unique()
     c, counts = torch.cat( (t1, t2)).unique(return_counts=True)
     common = c[torch.where( counts > 1 )]
     return common

In [544]: intersection(t1[0], t2[0])
Out[544]: tensor([1])

In [545]: intersection(t1[1], t2[1])
Out[545]: tensor([3])

In [546]: intersection(t1[2], t2[2])
Out[546]: tensor([], dtype=torch.int64)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't support batched inputs like you want. Unique has a dim parameter, but it doesn't work the way you'd need in order to do what you want in the outer dim. I suspect there might not be a way to get the batched behavior you want in PyTorch without looping over the outer dimension.

Maybe numpy and the [intersect operator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) might help somehow?